# php mysqli query function not executing when the query contains php variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would really like some help. I am trying to return a record from a table where I am search that table by first name and last name, which is one string in a php variable $employee_coor.

This problem is when ever I use the variable within my query statement it returns nothing. No errors nothing. However, if I echo the variable to the screen the employee's full name is seen. Then I tried copying that full name into the statement and the record would be then returned.

I also tried mysqli_num_rows on the query to be sure if a record is being selected or not and it returned 0 when echoed to the screen.

I really don't know why I am getting this, I hope it's something I am over looking or something like that.  The code below shows the script.

**UPDATE**: I tested the exact query itself in the MySQL client and it works perfectly. The only difference would be the query in MySQL qould have a full name as opposed to a php variable representing that name.

```
    <?php
     include_once('dbconnect.php');

     if (!empty($_GET['employees'])) {

     $employee_coor = $_GET['employees'];

     $select = "SELECT * FROM employees 
                WHERE employees.employee_fname = substring_index('$employee_coor',' ',1) 
                AND employees.employee_lname = substring_index('$employee_coor',' ',-1)";

           $query = mysqli_query($con,$select);

           $cooridinator = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

           var_dump($cooridinator);

   } else{}
   ?>
```

Comment: learn about concatenaton, your concatenating a variable/function from a string try doing it `'".substring_index()."'`. @Dez no, it will result to an error removing the single quotes.

Comment: @Dez If that is done it returns an error.

Comment: I'll try that method now @Rolijhon

Comment: 1. use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for the `$employee_coor`: `$employee_coor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['employees']);`. 2. `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is [MySQL function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) so leave it as is.

Comment: @Deadooshka yes it is I don't know why I let that slip my mind and listened to all these comments about concatenating... I'll try the escape api now

Comment: if it's about national encoding then you have to set proper one for the `Content-Type` http header and for the MySQL connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to stare at PHP code that builds an SQL query, and try to diagnose what's wrong with the SQL query. Why make it that hard?

If you have doubts about the SQL statement, you should print out the SQL and look at the SQL, not the PHP that builds SQL. I mean the final SQL string, after you have copied PHP variables into it. It might be more clear once you look at the final query why it doesn't work.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM employees 
           WHERE employees.employee_fname = substring_index('$employee_coor',' ',1) 
           AND employees.employee_lname = substring_index('$employee_coor',' ',-1)";

error_log($select);
```

Try copying the final SQL and trying it in the MySQL client. Does it give zero rows? Why? Try editing the query and removing one term of the WHERE clause, then the other. Do those give zero rows?

You get the idea. **Test, don't guess.**

Anyway, your code has another problem: it's vulnerable to SQL injection. It will break even if you try to process a person named "O'Reilly."

I would recommend splitting the variable in PHP before you apply it to the SQL statement, and also use bound parameters.

```
$employee_coor = explode(' ', $_GET['employees']);

$select = "SELECT * FROM employees 
            WHERE employees.employee_fname = ? 
            AND employees.employee_lname = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$select);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', 
  array_shift($employee_coor),
  array_pop($employee_coor));
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Hi, Bill a couple of things. I tested the exact query itself in the MySQL client and it works perfectly. Also I tried you method of exploding the string however I still get the same problem. Your advise was very useful though. I intend to address the SQL inject at a later date, however thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: "Security, like correctness, is not an add-on feature." — Andrew S. Tanenbaum

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you try to execute substring_index() inside your SELECT statement.  You can't do that.  The best thing to do is split your employee name into 2 variables before you use them in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

First you do $employee_coor = substring_index($_GET['employees'], ' ', 1);

You can add " . $employee_coor . " like the example:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM employeesWHERE employees.employee_fname = '" . $employee_coor . "' AND employees.employee_lname = '" . $employee_coor . "')";
```

Or you can do this way: {$employe_coor}, like the example:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees.employee_fname = '{$employee_coor}' AND employees.employee_lname = '{$employee_coor}'";
```

Or the simplest way: '$employe_coor':

```
    $select = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees.employee_fname = '$employee_coor' AND employees.employee_lname = '$employee_coor'";
```

Complete example:

```
<?php
include_once('dbconnect.php');

if (!empty($_GET['employees'])) {
    $employee_coor = substring_index($_GET['employees'], ' ', 1);
    //$select = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees.employee_fname = '$employee_coor' AND employees.employee_lname = '$employee_coor'";
    //$select = "SELECT * FROM employeesWHERE employees.employee_fname = '" . $employee_coor . "' AND employees.employee_lname = '" . $employee_coor . "')";
    $select = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees.employee_fname = '{$employee_coor}' AND employees.employee_lname = '{$employee_coor}'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $select);
    $cooridinator = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    var_dump($cooridinator);
} else {
    //code
}
```

?>